# First parameter as default in Scala

Tags: scala, default

Is there another way of making this work?

```
def b(first:String="hello",second:String) = println("first:"+first+" second:"+second)

b(second="geo")
```

If I call the method with just:

```
b("geo")
```

I get:

```
<console>:7: error: not enough arguments for method b: (first: String,second: String)Unit.
Unspecified value parameter second.
       b("geo")
```

Comment: def b(second: String) = b("hello", second)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one of the possible ways: you can use several argument lists and currying:

```
scala> def b(first:String="hello")(second:String) = println("first:"+first+" second:"+second)
b: (first: String)(second: String)Unit

scala> b()("Scala")
first:hello second:Scala

scala> val c = b() _
c: (String) => Unit = <function1>

scala> c("Scala")
first:hello second:Scala
```

Answer (score 3):

See scala language specifications 6.6.1 (http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

"The named arguments form a sufﬁx of the argument list e1, ..., em, i.e. no positional argument follows a named one."

Answer (score 2):

Providing a single string parameter (without naming it) is too ambiguous for the compiler.   *Probably* you meant the value for the non-default parameter, but... maybe not.  So the compiler wants you to be more specific.

Generally you put all your default parameters at the end of the method signature (if you did in this case, `b("geo")` would work) so that they can be left out less ambiguously.